# why am i not able to change the value of an variable of the parent class using a constructor in the child class?

Tags: java, constructor, super

```
class Parent{
    int a ;
    
    Parent(){
        
    }
    
    public int getA() {
        return a;
    }
    
    Parent(int c){
        this.a=c;
        System.out.println("I AM IN Parent AND THE VALUE OF a is : "+a);
        
    }
    
}
class Child extends Parent{
    Child(int c){
        super(c);
        System.out.println("I AM IN Child");
        
    }
}

public class Super {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        Parent one = new Parent();
        Child two = new Child(32);
        System.out.println(one.getA());
        

    }

}
```

//Output

I AM IN A AND THE VALUE OF a is : 32

I AM IN B

0

I am not able to change the value of the variable a of the parent class using a constructor in the child class

Comment: Why do you think two independent objects have a connections, just because they are related by type?

Comment: As a side note, the logic behind this seems flawed to me. In the real world a `Child` wouldn't be a 'subclass' of `Parent`. A `Parent` could contain a `List<Child>`, but a `Child` isn't obviously a `Parent`. It's just a side note but try to consider what it would be on the real world (you might have reasons though).

Comment: @PhilippeB. I don't think those classes exists for a real family hierarchy and are only named that way to match the usual parent-class <- child-class structure.

Comment: @Tom Oh yeah you're right ! That's the reason I was missing.

Answer (score 0):

the way you wrote the code, `one` is an instance of `Parent` and `two` is another instance of `Parent`, they are stored in different parts of memory and they are independent,

```
    Parent one = new Parent();
    Child two = new Child(32);
    System.out.println(one.getA());
    System.out.println(two.getA());
```

will output the following

```
I AM IN Parent AND THE VALUE OF a is : 32
I AM IN Child
0
32
```

which worked correctly.

Comment: Actually `two` is an instance of `Child` which inherit from `Parent`.